# isolating resources creating by two different users in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, subscription

I need to create two users in same subscription.Let users be A and B.the resource creating by user A should not be visible to user B and vice versa.It would be great if some one help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign RBAC to the user in the resource group Level, the user not able to access the resource until the user has permission to that resource group.

for more details please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

Answer (score 0):

it would depend on the type of resources being created. it works in a hierarchy fashion, so if a user had access to read and write resources under the subscription, then they could see it all the resources under that. but you could for example create a resource group and only give users access to that, so they won't see other resource groups that they don't have access to.

Other than that, you could create more subscriptions, then use management groups for a level of management above that.

there may be other options, like creating custom roles that only allow very specific creation and not reading resources and such, which may or may not work. but that would need to be tested.